# Android: custom code folding for strings.xml file in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio, formatting

I have small issue with the strings.xml file, when it is uploaded to a translation website. When the string is long and takes more than one line, Android Studio automatically adds a tab and the rest of the text is on the next line. The translators never know if this is part of the string or not. Is there a way I could prevent strings.xml being automatially indented when the string continues on the next line. Here is an example:

desired behaviour:

```
   <string name="one">one string</string>
   <string name="two">second string</string>
   <string name="long_string">kdfajdflJKF DLSKJDLJDF skjLFÑJDLFJDÑL
DAJHFJDKHFKAFK</string>
```

current behaviour:

```
    <string name="one">one string</string>
    <string name="two">second string</string>
    <string name="long_string">kdfajdflJKF DLSKJDLJDF skjLFÑJDLFJDÑL
    DAJHFJDKHFKAFK</string>
```

In the second example, in the file, extra spaces get added before the word DAJHFJDKHFKAFK so how could it prevent this? Where to look? I tried google search but I am not sure even how this feature would be called. What are the options? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio, go to
`File -> Settings`, in that under `Editor -> Code Style -> XML`, set `Indent = 0` and also, under the `Android` tab, set `Wrap attributes` to `Do Not Wrap`.

Comment: Thanks, that works but is there a way to do that but only for strings.xml? I would like the other files to be indented normally.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to just give you an alternative to the way you copy and paste, bet you didn't know this one... Hold down Alt and then drag the mouse over what you want to copy, you would see the beauty there

EDIT: Most translation websites are not built for codes, they are built for ordinary texts. So there is no way of changing that Android Studio feature that I know of, plus if you do edit it, any time you decide to share your code, it is going to look soo ugly with no proper indentation. (While writing this, I figured out that your solution would be to reduce the indent value... To do this, go to File >> Settings >> Search keyword "indent" and mess with stuff that comes up

Comment: I did not see anything, what am I supposed to see? How does this answer to my question? I am not copy pasting the strings

Comment: Hold down Alt key, then copy what you need, didn't you need to copy strings to a Translation Website?